# How to put four images 2x2 on other image as background, CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I try to put 4 images (same size) on 5th image defined as BG.

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

It works fine if `height` is fixed but in my case the `height` might change and I get this behavior:

[image]

This issue is not surprises me because I use `%` but not `px`.

When `width` changes, the style `left: 13%` changes

**Very important!!! I can use only "%"**

How can I achieve 1st image I posted even if height changes?

Here is relevant code:

```
<!-- BG image -->
<div style="position: relative; right: 0; top: 0; height:100%">   
    <img src="img/groups/pic-shade.png" style="
                             position: relative;
                             top: 0%;
                             right: 0%;
                             height: 17.6%;
                             ">  
     <!-- left-top image -->
    <img  
           style="position: absolute;
                  height: 42.25%;
                  top: 0%;
                  left: 0%;" src="img/group_6.png">
<!-- right-top image -->
    <img  
           style="position: absolute;
                  height: 42.25%;
                  top: 0%;
                  left: 13%;" src="img/group_6.png">

<!-- left-bottom image -->
    <img  
           style="position: absolute;
                  height: 42.25%;
                  bottom: 0%;
                  left: 0%;" src="img/group_6.png">

<!-- right-bottom image -->
    <img  
           style="position: absolute;
                  height: 42.25%;
                  bottom: 0%;
                  left: 13%;" src="img/group_6.png">
  </div>
```

**[EDIT]**

I tried to put `right: 0%` instead `left: 13%` but it doesn't help me because BG div has bigger width then BG image:

Here is root DIV selected:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w4JYh/)**

Don't use position absolute -- it breaks the flow and relationship between elements which means they can not show any response to each others width height changes.

Instead use the table technique -- check the demo.

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg-image-wrapper">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="cell"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="cell"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
    display:block;
}
.table{
    display: table;
}
.row{
    display: table-rwo;
}
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
}
.bg-image-wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: yes, but I have 5th image as BG. Do I need to use `bg-image-wrapper` as `absolute`?

Comment: do you want the bg image to cover more area then the images?

Comment: avoid position absolute as much as you can its not a good practice to create your layout structure on `position: absolute;`.

Comment: Actually BG image gives me some shadow and 4-5 pixels bigger then 2x2. Your example is works but only if BG has exactly the same size. BTW, this is a reason why I used `relative`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53886/discussion-between-imran-bughio-and-fessy)

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- BG image -->
<div style="background-image:url("img/groups/pic-shade.png"); position: relative;  right: 0; top: 0; height:100%">   

<table>
<tr>
<td>
                   <img style="height: 100%;width: 100%;src="img/group_6.png">
</td>
<td>
                   <img style="height: 100%;width: 100%;src="img/group_6.png">
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
                    <img style="height: 100%;width: 100%;src="img/group_6.png">
</td>
<td>
                    <img style="height: 100%;width: 100%;src="img/group_6.png">
</td>
</tr>

</div>
```

Comment: Its better to create to keep table structure with divs like i did - due to semantic reasons - Tables should only be used for tabular data.